# Self-Host Google Fonts PlayFair Display on Windows

Tags: web-fonts

I purchased the No Sidebar Pro theme for WordPress from StudioPress. I want to self-host the fonts rather than using Google Fonts for privacy reasons. I downloaded the .ttf files from the Google Fonts GitHub repo, and then I used the FontSquirrel generator to create the variety of formats for performance/cross-platform compatibility. FontSquirrel seems to create files for PlayFair Display that render crooked on Windows, however. To see what I mean, see the screenshot below.

[image]

Alternatively, I downloaded the latest files from the PlayFair Display GitHub repo. These, while rendering properly (not crooked) on Windows, seem to be a newer version of the font that render smaller than the current Google Fonts version of PlayFair Display.

The only solution I can think of to use that would render PlayFair Display correctly on Windows is to use the .ttf from the Google Fonts repo no matter what browser/platform is accessing my site. I'd really prefer to get woff2 and woff working, however.

I suppose I could tweak the stylsheet to bump up the font-size of the files from the PlayFair Display repo to try to match the Google Fonts size, but I am trying to avoid hacky workarounds and modifying the child theme more than I have to.

Is there any way to download all of the font formats from Google Fonts directly (not using FontSquirrel to convert)? Are there any other ideas that you have for rendering self-hosted PlayFair Display properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to download all formats from Google Fonts using this tool. It now works!

https://google-webfonts-helper.herokuapp.com/fonts

Comment: Glad you found a solution to your problem! Don't forget to accept your own answer if it solves your problem (This prevents it from showing up in the list of unanswered question)